# Windows Memory I/O error - Windows VM or ESXi host?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi

We have a terminal server that is getting a reoccurring memory error when users are running a certain application.

Previously the error occurred when trying to launch the application. A reboot fixed it for a few weeks. Now the error happened again when they run certain reports inside the application. This same application is used by almost every user and the memory error only happens on the terminal server.

The application is not installed on the server itself, it's run from a network share that is hosted on a different server.

The terminal server is Windows 2012 R2. ESXi is 6.5 Update 1 Build 5969303.

We've rebooted the server again to buy us some time but fear it will happen again.

Is the issue related to the VM or the host?

[Screenshot of memory error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zqvr.png)

Comment: In general, such errors have more relevance with the application. Not necessarily something wrong with the VM or host. Unless there's a hardware error on the host like a faulty memory chip, although in such case you would notice instabilities in other VMs also. Is it a stand-alone ESXi? If it's a cluster, you could try to migration (vMotion) the VM to another host to check its behaviour there. You could also try to change the VM's memory settings, to allocate all assigned RAM of the VM, no memory ballooning (which is enabled by default on ESXi).

Comment: @Krackout Unfortunately not part of a cluster, would have to manually move it to another host. No other VMs are experiencing any memory issues like the screenshot. I did change the memory setting by adding more memory, hoping it would allocate different RAM. Let me check on that setting you mentioned.

Comment: @TomTom i provided a lot of info.... instead of being negative, maybe ask what more info you want/need?

Comment: @TomTom cool thanks for zero help.

Comment: This indicates an I/O error while loading some of the application's code. If the application is on a network share, the issue is probably around accessing that share reliably. The error is UNEXPECTED_NETWORK_ERROR, further supporting this. (I've heard that mistakenly letting a firewall block some ports required for domain controller communication, such as UDP port 464, can cause this.)